# To prove a function is convex

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

> Consider the function $f : (0,1) \to \Bbb R^+$ defined by $$f(x) := \frac{1-x}{x} \left(\exp\left(\frac{k}{1-x}\right)-1 \right)$$ where $k > 0$ is a constant. Prove that $f$ is convex.

---

I checked its graph. It is convex, but I am not able to prove. Here is my try:

$$f''(x) = \frac{1}{x^{2}(1-x)^{3}} \left[ 2kx(1-x) + k^{2}x - 2k(1-x)  \right] + \frac{2}{x^{3}} \left( e^{\frac{k}{1-x}} -1 \right).$$

Somehow, I need to prove that $f''(x) \ge 0$, but not able to prove. I used the fact that $0<x <1$, but still not getting any conclusion. I checked the graph of $f''(x)$, it is above x-axis but still proof is required. Any help would be appreciated.

Also let me know if there is any other method to check if it is convex.

Comment: If $k < 0$, then $f$ is not convex, you can see this by plotting the function. Your second derivative also seems wrong to me. 
Once you have the right second derivative, you can perhaps use the fact that for $k>0$, and $x \in (0,1)$ $\frac{k}{1-x} > k \geq 0$ since $0<1-x<1$. Hence, $e^{\frac{k}{1-x}}-1 > 0$.

Comment: Yes $k>0$, I checked derivative but still getting same result.

Comment: I do not know if this helps Let $\displaystyle h(x) = \frac{e^{kx} - 1}{x}$, $\displaystyle g(x) = \frac{1}{1 - x}$ and $m(x) = h(g(x))$; that is $\displaystyle m(x) = (1 - x)e^{\frac{x}{1 - x}} - 1$ and then $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{m(x)}{x}$. But $m(x)$ is convex because $h$ is increasing and convex, and $g$ is convex.

Comment: @Ari.stat Thanks for your solution. I think still it is not solving my problem.

Comment: [MetiTarski](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/papers/Arith/) might handle this.